# In-App Purchase doesn't work

Tags: iphone, in-app-purchase, mkstorekit

I want to add in-app purchases to my app, but I can't make it work. I'm using MKStoreKit 4.2.

Here is the buying code:

```
- (IBAction)onPayButtonPressed:(id)sender {
    [[MKStoreManager sharedManager] buyFeature:@"com.flowrower.TestApp.0.99.item"
     onComplete:^(NSString* purchasedFeature, NSData* receiptData)
     {
         NSLog(@"Purchased: %@", purchasedFeature);
     }
     onCancelled:^
     {
        NSLog(@"Cancelled");
     }];


    NSLog (@"END");
}
```

In output I'm always getting "END" only. So buyFeature doesn't work at all.

- Testing on iPhone 4S with iOS 6.0.
- Using Provision Profile with In-App Purchases support.
- There is Product ID "com.flowrower.TestApp.0.99.item" in iTunes Connect with status "Ready to submit"
- This product is consumble and I have added it to MKSoreKitConfigs.plist
- Everything's OK with Contacts, Bank and Taxes in iTunes Connect
- Logged off from iTunes and App Store on my device.
- Getting this message at app start: "NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore error: user.TestApp has no valid com.apple.developer.ubiquity-kvstore-identifier entitlement". I don't know is it related or not.

Comment: The IAP must be approved before you can test it, if I recall correctly.

Comment: As I know, it's not necessary.

Comment: Make sure you have registered your bundle app for  inApp purchase for testing (Sandbox) . Then you have added the product to sell under the application in itunes Connect. Then only you can test on device or simulator. You may follow this tutorial also: http://maniacdev.com/2010/03/great-step-by-step-store-kit-in-app-purchase-tutorial/

Comment: Still nothing. 
@iCreative what do you mean by this sentence: "Make sure you have registered your bundle app for inApp purchase for testing (Sandbox) ."

Comment: http://www.raywenderlich.com/2797/introduction-to-in-app-purchases    Please follow this tutorial step by step to get it donee. Let me know if any more issues...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with iOS 6. 12 days ago new version of MKStoreKit released and it work like a charm in iOS 6. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0):

if its not approved, you need to test in the sandbox. I don't know MKStoreKit but I think you need an adhoc certificate!?